# Error complex data not supported in spectral clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, valueerror, complex-data-types

I'm running spectral clustering on a similarity matrix which is 1000*1000. my similarity matrix is as follows:

```
matrix([[0.000, 0.031, 0.030, ..., 0.850, 0.867, 0.838],
        [0.031, 0.000, 0.005, ..., 0.780, 0.805, 0.781],
        [0.030, 0.005, 0.000, ..., 0.803, 0.823, 0.795],
        ...,
        [0.850, 0.780, 0.803, ..., 0.000, 0.024, 0.008],
        [0.867, 0.805, 0.823, ..., 0.024, 0.000, 0.014],
        [0.838, 0.781, 0.795, ..., 0.008, 0.014, 0.000]])
```

I created adjacency and degree matrix and Laplacian matrix and then calculated eigenvalues and eigenvectors and I used the second smallest eigenvalue to figure out which node should be placed in which category.:

```
e, v = np.linalg.eig(L)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[30, 6])
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(e)
ax1.title.set_text('eigenvalues')
i = np.where(e < 300)[0]
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(v[:, i[0]])
ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(v[:, i[1]])
ax3.title.set_text('second eigenvector with eigenvalue close to 0')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9K1k.png)

But when I want to run kmeans as below to separate point I have an error:

```
U = np.array(v[:, i[1]])
km = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3)
km.fit(U)
km.labels_
```

Error:

> **> ValueError: Complex data not supported [[-0.04866435+0.j]  [-0.04909432+0.j]  [-0.04840705+0.j]  [-0.04859193+0.j]  [-0.0514795
> +0.j],...]**

Can you help me to know why is this error? I searched alot but no result.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution to this, just insert two lines of code as follows:

```
e, v = np.linalg.eig(L)
e = e.real
v = v.real
```

This will allow the use of the data for KMeans.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation related to what `np.linalg.eig` returns:

> The eigenvalues, each repeated according to its multiplicity. The eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered. The resulting array will be of complex type, unless the imaginary part is zero in which case it will be cast to a real type. When a is real the resulting eigenvalues will be real (0 imaginary part) or occur in conjugate pairs

The eigenvalues you have computed are complex, and you can not use complex with a KMeans.

Comment: Thanks because of your answer. But what should I do? Does it mean, I can't cluster data by spectral clustering?

Comment: It is not easy to answer your question, since I don't know the problem you're trying to solve.  Can you assume that the real and imaginary part are two different dimension? Or, you can transform a complex number x+jy into a 2D value composed by modulus and phase. Maybe the best solution is find something in literature that can help you.